# Gobal log for job array [SLURM]

Tags: arrays, logging, slurm, hpc

In addition creating the individual log file for each array-job (ie, `sbatch --output=job_%A_%a.out ...`), is there any way of getting a final report with all run jobs and see what ones have crashed? Something like that:

```
839594_1    COMPLETE
839594_2    FAIL
839594_3    COMPLETE
839594_4    COMPLETE
839594_5    COMPLETE
839594_6    FAIL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should obtain the output you want with the `sacct` command:

```
sacct -X -j 839594 -o jobid%-30,state
```

You can also add `-n` to suppress the display of the column headers.

Note that all `PENDING` jobs will be summarised into a single line like so:

```
839594_[10-20]         PENDING
```

if tasks 10 to 20 are still pending.

Comment: Wow, so simple... but so nice! Thanks!